# is it OK to put asserations in React testing library's waitFor()?

Tags: javascript, react-testing

from the official docs https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/ which uses:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(mockAPI).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))
```

but what if my codebase does have a bug which causes the api (mocked by `mockAPI`) not being called, then how does the above statement can do unit test properly because after the default timeout (1000ms), `waitFor` won't call the callback again, so the `expect` is not being called to throw an error, then the bug is swallowed, unless `waitFor` is designed to call one more time after the timeout? but I didn't find the official docs mention it?